# $\inf\int_{0}^{1} {f'(x)}^2 dx$, when $f: [0,1] →\Bbb R,\; f(0) = 0,\; f(1) = 1,\; \exists f' \;\text{and}\; f\;$' is continuous on [0,1]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to

i) determine the infimum

ii) show that there's a function for which $\int_{0}^{1} {f'(x)}^2 dx$ is the infimum

iii) show if such function is unique.

I tried out several functions that suit the given condition, but couldn't see how $\int_{0}^{1} {f'(x)}^2 dx$ changes as $f(x)$ changes. How could we solve this problem?

Comment: Time to put a little more effort when writing questions here. Learn the easy directions to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I followed the directions but still failed to make things show up the way they should. I will make a closer look at the directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim.** *Let $\,\mathscr X=\{\,g\in C^1[0,1]: g(0)=0\,\,\& \,\,g(1)=1.\}$. Then then functional $\,\varPhi(\,g)=\int_0^1 \big(\,g'(x)\big)^2\,dx$, attains a global minimum at $\,f(x)=x$, i.e.
$$
\min_{g\in\mathscr X}\varPhi(g)=\varPhi(\,f)=1.
$$*

*Proof.* If $g\in\mathscr X$, then $g$ can be expressed as $g(x)=x+h(x)$, where $g\in C^1[0,1]$ and $g(0)=g(1)=0.$ We have that
$$
\varPhi(g)=\int_0^1 \big(g'(x)\big)^2\,dx=\int_0^1 \big(1+h'(x)\big)^2\,dx=1+2\int_0^1\,h'(x)\,dx+\int_0^1 \big(h'(x)\big)^2\,dx \\=1+\int_0^1 \big(h'(x)\big)^2\,dx\ge 1=\varPhi(\,f),
$$
since $\int_0^1 h'(x)\,dx=h(1)-h(0)=0$. Hence $\,\varPhi(g)\ge\varPhi(\,f)$, for all $g\in\mathscr X$.

**Uniqueness.** In particular, if $g(x)\not\equiv x$, then $h'\ne 0$, where $h(x)=g(x)-x$, and hence $\int_0^1\big(h'(x)\big)^2\,dx>0$, which implies that $\varPhi(g)>1=\varPhi(\,f)$. Thus $\varPhi$ possesses a unique minimiser.

**Note.** It can be shown with Calculus of Variation as well, but its quite complicated, if one wants a rigorous proof.

Comment: I can also see that f(x)=x suits the conditions for the infimum. Can we say that its uniqueness has been proven by the process above?

Comment: Yes, uniqueness is also proved, since if $g(x)\ne x$, then the above argument shows that $\varPhi(g)>1$.

Comment: @Care See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

So we want to maximize
$$J[y]=\int_{0}^{1} (y'(x))^2 \mathrm{d}x$$
We have that the Lagrange-function is $L(x, y, y')=(y')^2$, and we must have that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{ \partial y}$$
And you just need to solve this differential equation.

Comment: Sorry, there had been an error with the editor. I have edited the question, it's int_{0}^{1}. Still thank you for your response. Could there be any other way than making use of Lagragean?

Comment: @Care so you want to find the minima?

Comment: @Care Well, there might be other way. But I don't knos any. But this is the standard way of Calculus of Variations. You want to find the maxima of a functional, and that's the subject of Calculus of Variations.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a minima. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Care I think it's $0$. Check my edit. Edit: It's not good.

Comment: @Care  This procedure is applicable only if $y$ is twice differentiable, which we do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with variational calculus.
Let $y=f(x)$ and $g(x,y,y')=(y')^2=(f'(x))^2$. Then the function $f(x)$ that gives infimum satisfies
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y'}\right)=0,
\end{equation}
if we use the Euler–Lagrange equation. 
As $\cfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$,
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dx}\left(2f'(x)\right)=0\\
&f(x)=ax+b
\end{align}
where $a,b$ are constant. Using the condition that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$,
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x\ .
\end{equation}

Comment: Sorry, I had edited the question, there seems to have been an error. It's int_{0}^{1}. Thank you for your response nonetheless. Also could there be any other way than using Lagrangean?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way than this. But I think there is.